# Javascript fast load does not work in Liferay on WebLogic

Tags: liferay, weblogic

I have deployed Liferay 6.2 GA4 portal on WebLogic server 10.3.6.0. If the `javascript.fast.load` property is enabled, the packed javascript version is not got (downloaded) from **/combo** url. In web browser console the following errors are displayed:

```
GET https://www.mywebsite.cz/liferay-portal/combo/?browserId=other&minifierType=&languageId=en_US&b=6203&t=1448975784000&/liferay-portal/html/js/aui/color-base/color-base-min.js&/liferay-portal/html/js/aui/event-touch/event-touch-min.js&/liferay-portal/html/js/liferay/dockbar.js 404 (Not Found)

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'init' of undefined
```

Due to this for example dockbar doesn't work. From source code it looks like **ComboServlet** can't get servlet resources found in /combo url parameters. If `javascript.fast.load` is disabled, portal seems to work.

**Weblogic.xml:**

```
<weblogic-web-app
    xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/ejb-jar_3_0.xsd http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app/1.2/weblogic-web-app.xsd"
>
    <jsp-descriptor>
        <keepgenerated>true</keepgenerated>
        <page-check-seconds>60</page-check-seconds>
    </jsp-descriptor>
    <session-descriptor>
        <persistent-store-type>replicated_if_clustered</persistent-store-type>
    </session-descriptor>

    <container-descriptor>
        <prefer-application-packages>
            <package-name>antlr.*</package-name>
            <package-name>com.ctc.wstx.*</package-name>
            <package-name>org.antlr.*</package-name>
            <package-name>org.apache.commons.lang.*</package-name>
            <package-name>org.mozilla.*</package-name>
            <package-name>org.xmlpull.*</package-name>
        </prefer-application-packages>
        <optimistic-serialization>true</optimistic-serialization>
        <show-archived-real-path-enabled>true</show-archived-real-path-enabled>
    </container-descriptor>
    <context-root>/liferay-portal</context-root>

    <library-ref>
        <library-name>ext-portal-dependencies</library-name>
        <specification-version>1.0</specification-version>
        <implementation-version>1.0</implementation-version>
        <exact-match>false</exact-match>
    </library-ref>
</weblogic-web-app>
```

Does anybody know what could be the problem? Some WebLogic or Liferay settings? Thanks for any idea or help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several days of solving the problem I found the main cause of this problem was this:

Because the customer didn't want to have portal dependencies (portal-service.jar, portlet-api.jar, ...) as domain libraries, I deployed it as **Java EE Shared Libraries**. Obviously it works differently than I expected. So after persuasion of customer, I put liferay dependencies to domain lib folder and suddenly everything started to work.

Answer (score 1):

I've had a comparable problem long ago on tomcat when there were problems with the temporary file path - e.g. it growing too long. This might happen in a deeply nested filesystem, or when the total path length is limited.

One of the path-length-limiting factors that I'm aware of is an encrypted home folder on Linux. Also, if the temporary filesystem runs full, the compressed file won't be written and consequently can't be served to the browser.

Check something along those lines, and please report back.